# Diagnosing high CPU waiting

Tags: linux, hard-drive, central-processing-unit, top

I have a monitoring server that is running icinga/collectd/graphite with about 50 hosts. I have noticed high load/slugging performance on the box. If you take a look at top, you'll see:

Cpu(s): 0.6%us, 0.2%sy, 0.0%ni, 7.6%id, 23.4%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.2%si, 0.0%st

Notice the HUGE %wa value, which as far as I know means a network or disk bottleneck. ifconfig shows no dropping packets and there's not a ton of bandwidth going on, so that leaves disk issues, right? There's not a lot of disk writing going on either...iotop is reporting we're only writing a little over 1 MB per second and the RAID tool reports everything is A-OK and write caching is enabled.

How do I go about trying to figure out how to fix this?

UPDATE:
iostat -x output is:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.62    0.10    0.31    9.65    0.00   89.31

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.21    33.34   83.55   16.54  1599.94   399.07    19.97    43.21  416.98   3.71  37.13
```

Answer (score 2):

i/o wait is also generated by NFS, SMB and other remote filesystems.

Use `vmstat 2` to see a granular view of system performance including io wait.

Answer (score 1):

High wa generally does mean the OS is either waiting for network or disk. There is quite a nifty program called [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/). This tells you what the disk is up to, might be some help.

Comment: As I said in the post, I ran iotop and it's only doing 1 MB/s of total disk I/O.

Comment: ah sorry you did I missed that. are the drives in good health? Have you had a look at smartctl? 

Also try doing a bandwidth test on the network, iperf is a good program. Make sure you have no network bottlenecks.

Comment: 1mb per second is a useless indicator - like trying to find out whether the engine in a car is powerfull enough by looking at the tachometer in a city. I have a 8 disc RAID 10 Veloricaptors that at times only pulls 4-6 mb/s and is FULLY BUSY. Check something like IO wait stats if available - but MB is irrelevant, if the head moves a lot, that may be all that the disc gives you.